# Keras Sequential with multiple inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Given 3 array as input to the network, it should learn what links data in 1st array, 2nd array, and 3rd array.

In particular:

- 1st array contains integer numbers (eg.: 2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
- 2nd array contains integer numbers (eg.: 3, 2, 4, 6, 2)
- 3rd array contains integer numbers that are the results of an operation done between data in 1st and 2nd array (eg.: 6, 6, 20, 36, 14).
  As you can see from the example data here above, the operation done is a multiplication so the network should learn this, giving:
  `model.predict(11,2) = 22`.

Here's the code I've used:

```py
import logging
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


primo = np.array([2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
secondo = np.array([3, 2, 4, 6, 2])
risu = np.array([6, 6, 20, 36, 14])

l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])
model = tf.keras.Sequential([l0])

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, ), name="Pri")
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, ), name="Sec")
merged = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([input1, input2])
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    2,
    input_dim=2,
    activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid,
    use_bias=True)(merged)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    1,
    activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
    use_bias=True)(dense1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model([input1, input2], output)
model.compile(
    loss="mean_squared_error",
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))
model.fit([primo, secondo], risu, epochs=500, verbose = False, batch_size=16)
print(model.predict(11, 2))
```

My questions are:

- is it correct to concatenate the 2 input as I did? I don't understand if concatenating in such a way the network understand that input1 and input2 are 2 different data
- I'm not able to make the model.predict() working, every attempt result in an error

Comment: "every attempt results in an error". Please edit your question and share this error with us. We cannot help you debug your code if you don't tell us explicitly what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Your model has two inputs, each with shape (None,1), so you need to use `np.expand_dims`:

```
print(model.predict([np.expand_dims(np.array(11), 0), np.expand_dims(np.array(2), 0)]))
```

Output:

```
[[20.316557]]
```